# am I missing something in C code? programming 8051 MCUs

Tags: c, microcontroller, 8051

I am currently learning C, so I tried to program my AT89S52 MCU with programmer.

Compiling with sdcc works, and upload is also successful. but when I tried to make blink program, it is not doing the thing I expected. I made my own header file with blink function. Its purpose is to blink LED on P1.0 with given delay. but it looks like the delay does not work and it is really fast switching P1.0 on and off.

Here is basicIO.h

```
#include <8052.h>

unsigned int i = 0;
void delay(int dl)
{
    for(i=0;i<=dl;i++) { //repeat 1ms delay x times
        TMOD = 0x01;    // Timer0 mode1
        TH0 = 0xFC;      //initial value for 1ms
        TL0 = 0x66;
        TR0 = 1;      // timer start
        while(TF0==0);  // check overflow condition
        TR0 = 0;     // Stop Timer
        TF0 = 0;    // Clear flag
    }
    
}
void on(void) {
P1_0 = 0x00;
}
void off(void) {
P1_0 = 0xFF;
}
void blink(int valdl) {
    P1_0 = 0x00;
    delay(valdl);
    P1_0 = 0xFF;
}
```

and here is srccode.c:

```
#include <8052.h>
#include "basicIO.h"
void main(void)
{
    off();
    while(1)
    { 
        blink(100);
        blink(100);
    }
}
```

There is no error when running the `on`, `off` or `delay` functions, so what is happening with blink?

Comment: You also need to wait after turning the LED off, not only after turning it on, in `blink`. Otherwise after turning it off you immediately turn it on again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a simple misunderstanding and not a C programming problem.

Comment: It's not the cause of your issue, but header files should not contain function implementations.  They may, and often do, contain function prototypes, but the implementations should be separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all the functions but your main loop should be

```
while(1)
{   on()
    delay(100);
    off();
    delay(100);
}
```

or use

```
void blink(int valdl) 
{
    P1_0 = 0x00;
    delay(valdl);
    P1_0 = 0xFF;
    delay(valdl);
}
```